# ls with a wildcard

Tags: ls, quoting, wildcards, variable

This works from the terminal:

```
ls /dev/sda*
```

I want it in a bash script, using a variable. I tried:

```
device="a"
ls "/dev/sd"$device"*"
```

But I get the error: `ls: cannot access '/dev/sda*': No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ls /dev/sd$device* # or
ls "/dev/sd$device"*
```

You must not quote the globbing metacharacters if you want globbing to be performed.

Comment: The quoting in the original is almost exactly backward. You *can't* quote wildcards you want expanded; you *should* quote variable references to prevent unexpected word splitting and wildcard expansion on them; quoting fixed strings that don't contain any shell metacharacters doesn't matter. The original had the wildcard quoted and the variable reference unquoted, both of which should be reversed (as in the second option in this answer). BTW, `ls /dev/sd"$device"*` would also be fine since `/dev/sd/` doesn't contain any metacharacters.

Comment: Also globbing and quotes are done my the shell, `ls` knows nothing about them.

Comment: Amusingly, variable assignment works in such a way that you *can* write this:  `device=sda*; ls /dev/$device`, and get glob expansion after the variable substitution.

Comment: How will it work if there is an OR search in the variable value 
like:  device="(a|b)"

Answer (score 8):

The double quotes tell the shell to leave the `*` as-is instead of expanding it. This will work:

```
device="a"
ls "/dev/sd${device}"*
```